# Sharing package within a Python project with Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to reuse some code within my python project, within an Azure Function, it is structured as follows:

```
myproject/
| - a_app/
| - b_app/
| - c_lib/
| - requirements.txt
```

Up until now I have been conveniently avoiding sharing code between my 2 separate modules a_app and b_app. But I now want to create some classes that I can share and place it within c_lib.

I have an Azure function here:

```
myproject/
| - a_app/FunctionA/init.py
```

It is referencing the library c_lib by importing using the following statement:
from c_lib.foundation_utility.jwt_enforced_permissions import JWTEnforcedPermissions

All the tests pass locally and the reference is imported successfully but when I deploy to my Azure Function it simply can't find the library (an example class I'm trying to share):

File "/home/site/wwwroot/FunctionA/init.py", line 10, in from c_lib.foundation_utility.jwt_enforced_permissions import JWTEnforcedPermissions File "/home/site/wwwroot/c_lib/foundation_utility/jwt_enforced_permissions.py", line 4, in from foundation_utility.i_token_permissions import ITokenPermissions

For the life of me I can't figure out why it can't find the library. I am trying to browser the Azure Function folder structure so that I can figure out where the file is actually located to reconcile why it's not working.

Given that I have been able to reference various classes within my a_app and b_app respectfully, but not referencing one another, I know how to successfully call the right namespace.  I therefore thought about copying the c_lib into the folders of a_app/ and b_app/ respectfully as part of a github build action:

```
    - name: Copy c_lib into Function App Directory
      run: |
        cp -r c_lib a_app/
```

However despite doing this and trying to reference c_lib from within a_app it still not working.
I also considered creating this library as a pip module, but that's not what I'm looking for as I want to deploy the library as the same version as a_app and b_app.  I don't want version invariance.

Something about the Azure Function means that it can't access code beyond its own package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer my [SO answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948912/azure-functions-no-module-named-app-appname-error-codes/76950852#76950852) where I have imported class from another folder to **`init.py`**. If you have python custom library in c_lib you can import those libraries by adding the folder path in requirements.txt, Refer my [SO answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749362/install-linux-dependency-during-the-python-webapp-zip-deployment-azure-oryx/77925172#) for the same.

In order to resolve your error refer the steps below:-

***My Functions folder: -***

My `init.py` has this code added with ***`sys.path.append`*** that imports the **`c_lib`** files coreectly in both the Apps: -

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func

import sys

import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'c_lib'))

# Now you can import your shared classes
from c_lib.foundation_utility.jwt_enforced_permissions import JWTEnforcedPermissions
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will be using this library in many places, so writing:
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'c_lib'))

At the top of every file doesn't seem scalable / clean.

Are you suggesting I can instead add an entry to my requirements.txt?
e.g. adding "./c_lib" into the top of the file so it would look like this:

== requirements.txt ==
./c_lib
aiohttp==3.9.3
aiosignal==1.3.1

Comment: Just adding ./c_lib will install all the packages from c_lib via requirements.txt

Comment: That worked well thank you.  I did have to copy the c_lib as part of my github build action into the directory as well as the requirements.txt but it works nicely - thanks!